# Change HDD icon in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer, icons, desktop

How can I change the icon of one of my HDDs in Windows 7, not using the autorun.inf trick?  I'm trying to speed up my laptop for every day use as much as possible so I mapped my desktop to a RamDisk.  I would like the ramdisk's icon to be the desktop icon, but since the ramdisk can't have any files in it while it is being initialized and autorun file would never run.

Are there any other ways to change the icon of a drive?  Here is a screen shot of what I am talking about.

Here it is in my users folder.
[image]

And in the my computer window.
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set the default icon in the Registry.

In RegEdit, open `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\DriveIcons`. There may or may not be any subkeys.

Find or create a subkey(folder) with the drive letter as its name.

In that key, create a subkey(folder) named `DefaultIcon`. Change the `(Default)` value of the `DefaultIcon` key to the path of the icon you want to use.

i.e.

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\DriveIcons\Z\DefaultIcon]
@="C:\\Foo\\MyIcon.ico"
```